# How can I find out if a document has focus in chrome developer console

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to see if my document has focus using this API.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hasFocus

So what I am doing is load my page and the in Chrome developer console, I type 'document.hasFocus()'

The problem is it always return false.that is because after I load the page, i need to click on the chrome developer console before I can type 'document.hasFocus()' and execute that method.

So that gives the console focus.

How can I work around this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: How exactly is this a problem? You are checking if your document has focus when it doesn't have focus and correctly being told that it does not. Do you want a function that tells you that your document has focus when it doesn't?

Comment: I think since i move the focus away from the document by click on the chrome developer console, so the document will always has no focus in my debugging.

Comment: Right. So why is that a problem? It doesn't have focus, and it knows it doesn't have focus. Do you want some way to tell the app it has focus when it doesn't? If so, write your own `hasFocus` function that overrides the test if some other parameter is set and call that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of running the command from the console, create a button on your page. When clicked, logged the output of the method.

```
<button type=button onclick="function() {console.log(document.hasFocus());}">Do I have focus?</button>
```